# differences in forecast and reconstruction in SSA, in R

Tags: r, nonparametric, spectral-analysis, singular-matrix

I was playing around with the Rssa when I discovered this:

[image]

Firstly:
I created to sequences:

```
library Rssa
x<-1:100
x1<-1:80
```

then the corresponding function:

```
fx<-sin(x)
fx1<-sin(x1)
```

then I passed all into the ssa:

```
s<-ssa(fx1)
plot(s,"vectors)
#obviusly the first two comps represent the sin func.#
r<-reconstruct(s,groups=list(1:2))
f<-rforecast(s,groups=list(1:2),len=20,only.new=FALSE)
f1<-vforecast(s,groups=list(1:2),len=20,only.new=FALSE)
plot(fx)
lines(f)
lines(f1,col="red")
lines(r$F1,col="blue")
```

What happened in your opinion?
Why the forecasts do not correspond with the original series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code does not correspond to the figure.
This figure is obtained with groups=list(1:1), that is, by one eigentriple, not two.